# Alterar a transição do Slide Bootstrap

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, transações, slide, slideshow

Preciso diminuir o tempo de transição do slide `Bootstrapp`, como posso fazer sendo que os arquivos `js` e `css` estão sendo puxados do site?

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner_lctl2_min.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner_home_4_min.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/perfiladeira-min-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner-home-5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner_profil_min.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
<h1>Inovação e Tecnologia <br> no processamento de bobinas</h1>
<button type="button" class="botao-topo">Conheça nossa Empresa</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara sua resposta está na documentação: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#options

O valor que vc coloca no `data-interval="X"` é o tempo que vai demorar a transição entre um slider e outro.

Então a tag do slider ficaria assim para passar de 1 em 1 segundo por exemplo.

```
<div data-interval="1000" id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide"  data-ride="carousel">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div data-interval="1000" id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner_lctl2_min.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner_home_4_min.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/perfiladeira-min-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner-home-5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="http://www.esquadros.com.br/Img/Sitecomp/banner_profil_min.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
        <h1>Inovação e Tecnologia <br> no processamento de bobinas</h1>
        <button type="button" class="botao-topo">Conheça nossa Empresa</button>

      </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})`em Javascript tbm

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus sim da pra fazer direto pelo JS tb. Até editei minha resposta pra demonstrar direito o exemplo, pq como o `data-interval="n"` vc configura direto na tag caso tenho mais de um slider na página facilita etc

Comment: Obrigado galera! Deu certo.

Comment: @RenanRanzani tranquilo jovem, que bom que funcionou. Se vc achar que está respondido considere marcar ess ícone `✔` abaixo das setinhas ai ao lado da resposta. Assim sua Pergunta não fica pendente sem resposta aceita, mesmo já tendo sido resolvido. Abs

Comment: Feito, obrigado!